# What's the type of polymer material used in friction bushings in Sram rear derailleurs clutches?

Tags: mountain-bike, derailleur, technology

The friction bushing of an (older) Sram rear derailleur clutch is shown below. What type of polymer material are these made out of? I'm also interested to know what friction materials are used in the clutches of derailleurs from other brands, such as Shimano, etc.

[image]

Comment: Almost certainly an industrial secret!

Comment: Probably Teflon bushings?